# How to extract undo/redo transformations from OpenRefine Client?

Tags: python, openrefine

I am using the OpenRefine client: https://github.com/opencultureconsulting/openrefine-client

I need to automate processes and for this I need to be able to extract/export OpenRefine transformation history (undo/redo) in JSON format from the client, however, the client does not have a command for it. Is there any way to extract that history from the client?

Or does anyone know a way to extract that history from python?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know extracting the [OpenRefine project history](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/running#history-undoredo) is not part of the public API of [openrefine-client](https://github.com/opencultureconsulting/openrefine-client) (latest version checked [v0.3.10](https://github.com/opencultureconsulting/openrefine-client/releases/tag/v0.3.10)).

But *openrefine-client* provides a method to perform arbitrary commands, as long as they are supported by the [OpenRefine API](https://docs.openrefine.org/technical-reference/openrefine-api). In your case that would be the `get-operations` command.

So I expect you can just do something like this in Python:

```py
from google.refine import refine

server = refine.Refine('http://localhost:3333')

project_id = '1234567890123'
project = server.open_project(project_id)

operations = project.do_json('get-operations')
```